# how should I send html page in send_mail() method of django core?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

So I am newbie in django and I am using send_mail() method of django.I want to send html page as a email by usnig that method.How should I do that?

I have tried using jina template to send html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/), the `send_mail` function has a `message` parameter and an `html_message` parameter.  Send the plain text part in `message`, and the HTML part in `html_message`.

You always need a plain text part because some mail readers don't handle HTML.